# time java using while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

i want to get the value of time every time i set an advance minutes and if the minute will be sixty it must automatically add one hour then the minutes will be zero.
this is my code in my class.

```
public class time {
  private int hours;
  private int minutes;
  private String amPm;

  public time() {
  }

  public time(int hours, int minutes, String amPm) {
    this.hours = hours;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.amPm = amPm;
  }

  public void advance(int aminutes){
    if(minutes > 0){
      minutes = minutes + aminutes;
      while(hours < 0){

      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String time = hours + " " + minutes + " " + amPm + ".";
    return time;
  }
}
```

what is the missing in my code because it shows an error?

Comment: I can see a couple of significant issues there, but it'd be helpful if you posted details of the error also.

Comment: while(hours < 0){

      } what is it ?

Comment: Also, can you just confirm this is a homework assignment? If not, all this behaviour is built into the Java standard libraries, so you don't need to build it!

Comment: I want the manual way with out depending on the libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively simple.

Add the `advance` to the `minutes`, if the `minutes` greater then 59, divide the `minutes` by 60, this will give the number of hours that have begin added.  Next you mod the `minutes` by 60 to get the number of remaining minutes...

```
public void advance(int aminutes) {
    minutes = minutes + aminutes;
    if (minutes > 59) {
        int moreHours = Math.round(minutes / 60);
        minutes = minutes % 60;
        hours += moreHours;
    }
}
```

Now, the question is.  Why not just use a `Calendar` instead??

```
public class Time {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.advance(90);

        System.out.println(time);
    }

    private Calendar cal;

    public Time() {
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    }

    public Time(int hours, int minutes) {
        this();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    }

    public void advance(int aminutes) {
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, aminutes);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String time = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return time;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to have the manual way not depending on libraries.

Comment: `Calendar` is part of the Core libraries, they come with Java, but, that's you choice.

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer is very true Use **java.util.Calendar** class. This class is more intelligent than Date.

Below is sample code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" :: "+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 80);

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" :: "+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

It will automatically do addition to hour field if minutes increases more than 60.